# python koan - simplifying this two liner into one

Tags: python

I wan to turn this two lines of code into one.

```
for n in exceptions:
    my_dict[n] += 1
```

It's bothering me that a small statement to increment a dictionary takes two lines. I'm sure this problem has bothered someone too.

Comment: It is a really nice question, of how to make an operation to all the elements in a data structure in python. I would rewrite it

Comment: Why does it bother you to use two lines?

Comment: @0x90 like this? `map(lambda n: d.update({n: d[n] +1}), exceptions)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
for n in exceptions: my_dict[n] += 1
```

...but there is *nothing wrong* in the fact that the statement takes two lines. There are some python [coding guidelines (PEP8)](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) and they strongly encourage core readability. By putting those statements into a single line you lower the readability.

From [PEP8](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/):

> While sometimes it's okay to put an if/for/while with a small body on
>   the same line, never do this for multi-clause statements. Also avoid
>   folding such long lines!

Answer (score 3):

```
my_dict.update({n: my_dict[n] + 1 for n in exceptions})
```

This essentially uses [dict.update](http://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict.update) to update the dictionary with values from another dictionary. And that other dictionary is built using a dictionary comprehension. Unfortunately, to get the `my_dict[n] += 1` effect, we have to read the value explicitely again in the expression.

But I would argue **a lot** if it would be better than using a **simple** and **clear** for-loop for this.

On the other hand, as you seem to be just counting exceptions, you might want to consider using a [Counter](http://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) for your dictionary. It’s essentially an improved dictionary (meaning that you can use it just like a normal dictionary) but it comes with a few features that makes it perfect when counting things. For example, you could simplify above statement to just this:

```
my_dict.update({n: 1 for n in exceptions})
```

Or as you are just adding `1` for each, you can just pass the iterable `exceptions` directly:

```
my_dict.update(exceptions)
```

This would also have the benefit that  exceptions which do not exist in `my_dict` yet, are automatically initialized. To create a Counter from your existing dictionary, you can just pass the original dictionary to the Counter constructor:

```
from collections import Counter
my_dict = Counter(my_dict)
```

Comment: *"I would argue a lot if it would be better than using a simple and clear for loop."* - make that bold :)

Comment: I agree with you both. I'll condense the for loop into one line.

Answer (score 2):

Use a [collections.Counter](http://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.Counter):

```
import collections
my_dict = collections.Counter(exceptions)
```

or, if `my_dict` is already defined to be a `dict`,

```
my_dict = collections.Counter(my_dict)
my_dict.update(exceptions)
```